# Texto da barra de título no centro

Tags: c#, winforms

O texto da barra de título do Form no meu Visual Studio 2015 está à esquerda, por padrão. Como fazer para que ele fique centralizado por padrão? Grato.

Comment: Talvez isso ajude: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/93959/WinForm-Extended

Comment: ou talvez isto https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/260240/Windows-Form-Title-Bar-Text-alignment

Comment: Aqui tem o que voce precisa: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11947314/how-to-center-align-the-title-bar-text-in-windows-form

Answer (score 1):

Naturalmente, não é possível.

Existem duas formas de lidar com isto, nenhuma das duas é fácil e talvez nenhuma seja boa para o caso específico.

1. Criar um *form* personalizado.

   Isso é um tanto trabalhoso, porém traz muita liberdade. Em contrapartida, com a liberdade vem a responsabilidade de fazer tudo certinho. Não são muitas coisas a se tratar, então acho que é uma opção cogitável se precisares de mais coisas que não existam naturalmente nos *forms*.

   Esta opção é boa caso precise modificar mais coisas, caso contrário eu acho que a melhor ideia é se conformar com o título à esquerda mesmo.

   Este não é o foco desta pergunta, então, se tiver interesse, acho interessante que abra outra pergunta sobre esta questão específica. Tenho certeza que surgirão ótimas respostas.
2. Criar um método que edite o título conforme o tamanho do *form* adicionado espaços a esquerda e a direita para centralizá-lo. Este é o famoso "modo gambiarra".

   Basicamente, o que precisa ser feito é chamar o método que faz este cálculo ao carregar o form, usando o evento [`Load`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.windows.forms.form.load(v=vs.110).aspx) e sempre que alterar o tamanho do mesmo, usando o evento [`ResizeEnd`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.windows.forms.form.resizeend(v=vs.110).aspx).

   Perceba que você terá que calcular o espaço dos botões normais de uma janela (minimizar, restaurar e fechar) e que isso ainda **pode variar** dependendo do sistema operacional, uma vez que estes *forms* serão diferentes em cada versão do Windows. Além disto, o nome do *form* **não vai aparecer na barra de tarefas** porque será muito longo.

   A base deste código é isto.

   ```
   private void UpdateTextPosition()
   {
       var grap = CreateGraphics();

       var pontoInicio = (Width / 2) - (grap.MeasureString(Text.Trim(), Font).Width / 2);
       var larguraEspaco = grap.MeasureString(" ", Font).Width;

       var tituloTemp = " ";
       double larguraTemp = 0;

       while ((larguraTemp + larguraEspaco) < pontoInicio)
       {
           tituloTemp += " ";
           larguraTemp += larguraEspaco;
       }

       Text = tituloTemp + Text.Trim();
   }
   ```